# Django Как сделать дефолтные Гет запросы?

Tags: html, django

Есть 2 Get запроса, чтобы фильтровать товар ( смотрите картинку)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<form class ="form for_change_items" method="get" name="for_change_items" >
                                   
                                        <div class="form-check" >
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="change_items" id="2_items" value="2_items"   onClick="for_change_items.submit()" >
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="2_items">
                                                    <img class="img_right_menu" src="../../../static/img/2_items.jpg" alt ="Профиль">
                                                </label>
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="change_items" id="many_items" value="many_items"   onClick="for_change_items.submit()" >
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="many_items">
                                                    <img class="img_right_menu" src="../../../static/img/many_items.jpg" alt ="Профиль">
                                                </label>
                                        </div>
                            </form>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при заходе на страницу, я сразу получал какие-то дефолтные значения
Например = http://127.0.0.1:8000/first_item/?model_or_item=model?change_items=many_items

Comment: такие штуки лучше через куки делать, а не через гет

Comment: Нужно чтобы они именно в адресе появились? Или нужно, чтобы если в запросе нет параметров, то приложение себя вело так, будто они есть? Если первый случай, то можно сделать редирект из view, если список парметров пуст. Если второй случай, то  просто проверить параметр на пустоту и задать ему какое-то значение для дальнейшей обработки.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вариант, плохой, но вариант - при переходе не страницу без GET параметров редеректить на дефолтные ДО загрузки страницы
2. Не отображать дефолтные значения в адресной строке и использовать их только на серверной части, а-ля:

```
if not uses_other_get_params:
    sort_by = default_sort
```

3. И да, куки лучше. Или сессии